# Changing Apple Mac environment www record

Tags: domain-name-system, mac, mac-osx-server

Apple server gurus? I have a Mac OSX Snow Leopard server question. How to be able to view a company's externally hosted website from inside the company?

I inherited a company using Mac OSX Snow Leopard server. We moved the website away from MobileMe and into an environment that offers PHP etc.

Although the site shows up correctly outside of the company, internally it looks to the MobileMe page and shows an error.

I need to change the www record to reflect the change. Where do I do this on OSX Server?

Comment: More detail please. This sounds like you might be in a split DNS situation, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this link might help: http://www.inertramblings.com/2004/05/11/mac-os-x-clearing-dns-cache/

Doing some searches related to OSX's DNS or BIND configuration might assist you as well.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem that's peculiar to the mac. Nor am I sure it's a DNS problem as such.

The website is probably defined to only respond to the *'www.example.com'* host header. You need to add the URL that is used for internal access to the list of acceptable host headers for that website. As I don't have a mac server at home I can't give you the precise steps to follow but if you open server manager, expand the web server section and look at the settings for that particular site it should be easy enough to figure out.